# Blazor - child component created multiple times - when EditForm.Model changes

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a razor page with a child component.

When I visit the page, the page instance is created only once but the child instance is created twice.

```
@page "/somepage/Id:int"
<EditForm Model="Model">
   <h1>Parent<h1>
   <Child Model="Model"/>
</EditForm>

@code
{
   object Model = new object();
   public Parent()
   {
      //this is created once
   }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Model = new object();
    }
   ....
}
```

Child.razor

```
<h3>Child - @Id</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public object Model { get; set; }

    public Child()
    {
        // created twice
    }
}
```

Why is that and is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: When an EditForm model changes, it recreates all child controls - the only way around it is to not use EditForm AFAIK. You could wrap your Child in an `@if (Model is object)...` block - that may prevent the first create

Comment: Model is changed twice :`object Model = new object();`,   `Model = new object();`